# Load menu just when it is needed

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I get my page overloaded after I add to many contents 
I'm calling contextmenu (righmenu) via javascript but when it haves many contents pages loads so slowly

here is my JavaScript rightClick menu:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        context.init({preventDoubleContext: false});


        context.attach('#ID', [
        {text: '<i class="el-icon-download-alt" style="color: #1AADC1"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Download', href: '#', extra: 'target="_blank"'},
        {divider: true},
        {text: '<i class="el-icon-link" style="color: #3CC8DB"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Export Link', href: '#link_ID', extra: 'class="popup-with-form"'},
        {text: '<i class="el-icon-share-alt" style="color: #3CC8DB"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Share', subMenu: [
        {text: '<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg" style="color: #009688"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Email', href: '#', target:'_blank', },
        {text: '<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" style="color: #0D47A1"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Facebook', href: '#', target:'_blank', },
        {text: '<i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg" style="color: #F44336"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Google+', href: '#', target:'_blank', },
        {text: '<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" style="color: #42A5F5"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Twitter', href: '#', target:'_blank', }
        ]}, 
        {divider: true},
        {text: '<i class="el-icon-remove" style="color: #DB3C4C"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Delete', href: '#del_ID', extra: 'class="modal-basic"'},
        {text: '<i class="el-icon-font" style="color: #3CDBAE"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Edit', href: '#', extra: 'class="simple-ajax-popup"'},
        {divider: true},
        {text: '<i class="el-icon-cog" style="color: #48A360"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Properties', href: '#info_ID', extra: 'class="popup-with-form"'},
    ]);

    context.settings({compress: true});
});
</script>
```

ID is different on all.

HTML code:

```
<div id="ID"  class="thumbnail">
    <label for="cID"><div class="thumb-preview">
    <a class="thumb-image" href="<TMPL_VAR img_preview>">
        <img src="#" class="img-responsive" alt="Project">
    </a>
    <div class="mg-thumb-options">
        <div class="mg-toolbar">
            <div class="mg-option checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="demo" id="cID" value="ID">
                <label for="c<TMPL_VAR file_id>">SELECT</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<h5 class="mg-title text-weight-semibold">Demo Test</h5>
```

So I have that it's okay if i have just 4 or 5 content but up of that its slow down my site, 
I want to have just one dropdown menu, menus I dont need to add JavaScript code for all HTML content.

Comment: Okay so you have a drop down menu and you want to reduce its size right?  But the size here seems to be fixed. Can you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: no i dont want to reduce size but if i have loads of html code and javascript ,, my page will load slowly

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your `HTML` code in jQuery function. Instead use jQuery to only hide or show the drop down menu. No need to add HTML inside it. Put the HTML back wrap it with a div. Show/hide that div using jQuery `$(#id).show()/hide()`.